# 'npm' 'node' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file for Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, graalvm

Installing nvm nodejs on Windows. nvm works fine but npm or node returns me "is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I have included the paths to PATH:
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MONGODB_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;

where NVM_SYMLINK refers to C:\Program Files\nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Graalvm Java comes with nodejs (C:\Program Files\graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0\bin\ with npm.cmd node.cmd npx.cmd) and they do not work. If %JAVA_HOME%\bin in PATH comes before nodejs config (%NVM_SYMLINK%;) the npm, node, npx from Java are executed instead.

it should be:

**%NVM_SYMLINK%;**%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MONGODB_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;%NVM_HOME%;

Comment: They should work, can you please create an issue at github.com/graalvm/graaljs about it? Thank you!

Comment: even if it works, it creates confusion to me because I was expecting the NodeJs version I installed not GraalVM version's. More, I was not aware Java includes NodeJs at all.